# Android app session duration of less than 1 second

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

My Android app uses `google play services` version 10.2.0.
In `Google Analytics` dashboard I see that 36% of app sessions have a duration of less than 1 second. What could be the reason?

(Users repeatedly opening/closing app for fun or is this a bug in GA?)